# How to prevent conflicts between ngAnimate and ngClass from breaking the DOM?

Tags: angularjs, css-transitions, ng-animate, ng-class

I just started using the ngAnimate library (1.2.13) and it's breaking my DOM when I use the ngRepeat directive in combination with ngClass.
There seems to be a conflict when ngClass adds or removes classes that trigger an existing transition not defined with the ngAnimate classes.

I have replicated the behaviour in the following Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iw5st35cqp1GQeCxMhjj
When you click one of the elements they get get focused. The class `dm-focused` is added to the element with ngClass and triggers a transition in height. When the focused element is removed it should disappear from the list but instead it glitches out and is stuck in the focused state.

The only solution I could come up with is to set every ngAnimate class to `transition: none` for all of the existing classes that suffer from this glitch.
But what if I do want to use transitions with both ngClass and ngAnimate? I would also have to go through all of my application and add unnecessary styling just to prevent this unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Think it's best solution to use classes only for some specific actions - not animation.

In any case you can disable animation for the element

**in js:**

```
app.directive('disableAnimate', ['$animate', function ($animate) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            $animate.enabled(false, element);
        }
    };
} ]);
```

**In html:**

```
<div disable-animate><!-- your structure --></div>
```